# linked list/ read from file/c++

Tags: c++, file, pointers, linked-list, ifstream

I have the following data structure:

```
struct Domino{
    int numb1; 
    int numb2;
    bool used;
    Domino* next;
};
```

And i have to read the elements from a file with the structure:

```
3  
1 2 
2 2 
4 1
```

The first number shows the number of the lines.
I wrote the following function:

```
    Domino* read(char* filename, Domino* head){ 
    std::ifstream file;
    int first=0,line=0, numb, prev_numb, cnt=1;
   file.open(filename, std::ios_base::in);
    if(!file){
        std::cout<<"File cant be opened"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while(file>>numb){
        if(line==0){
            line++;
        }else{
        if(cnt%2!=0){
            prev_numb=numb;
            cnt++;
        }else{
            Domino* stone=new DominoListe;
            stone->numb1=prev_numb;
            stone->numb2=numb;
            stone->used=false;
            if(head==NULL){
                head=stone; //first element in the list
            }else{
                Domino* tmp=head;
                while(tmp->next!=NULL){
                    tmp=tmp->next; //The End of the list is found
                }
                tmp->next=stone; // Append at the End
                        }
            stone->next=NULL;
            if(first==0){
                head=stone;
                first++;
            }
            cnt++;
    }}}
    file.close();
    std::cout<<"File is read.\n"<<std::endl;
    return head;
    }
```

Calling function:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) { // noch mit const!
Domino* head=NULL;
head=read(argv[1], head);
...
```

The file is read but a list isnt build as expected, the head is after the running of this function still 0. When I write simply 
`file.open("filename");` 
everything is ok and the program runs properly and every pointer shows where it should show. 
However, I tried to call the program with

> ./progname progname.cpp "filename"

and also without the quotes, but the result is the same-the file is read, head is always 0.

Can somebody explain me why is there such difference?

Comment: It is because i call the function with head=read(...), and so its initialized after the return head command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is going to read `progname.cpp` because it is specified as the first argument, and what is in the first line of `progname.cpp` may not be what can be interpreted as a number.

Try removing the extra argument and launching the program like

```
./progname "filename"
```

Also note that you should check the number of arguments before using them.